# Difference among 優れた機能 vs. 優れる機能 vs. 優れている

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words

I've recently purchased a Windows computer and at the first time log in, it displays the following message:

> たくさんの優れた機能をお楽しみください

I wonder why 優れた is used in this case.

Shouldn't 優れる be the correct choice?

What does it affect to the meaning of the sentence if I want to use 優れている?